# Pass value to tableview with navigation controller storyboard

Tags: iphone, ios5, ios6, storyboard, uistoryboardsegue

how do i pass a value to a table view controller that has a navigation controller?

i have code to push the new view controller and make it active but no way of passing a value to the table view.

```
UIViewController *newTopViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:identifier];
```

the problem is that i dragged a navigation controller onto the storyboard and it came attached to a tableview. i linked that tableview to my custom tableview class. When i instantiate the view controller from the name "nav", which is the storyboard id of the navigation controller, i get the navigation controller as the view controller being instantiated (newTopViewController); so how do pass a value from where i instantiate the view to the tableview controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass it inside prepareForSegue if your already going to be segueing to that VC.

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"whateverYourSegueIsCalled"])
   {
        YourTableViewController *tableView=(YourTableViewController*)segue.destinationViewController;
        tableView.anyPublicProperty = yourValue;
    }
}
```

EDIT:

Okay so since you actually just have the tableView embedded, you simply need to access the viewControllers property of the navigationViewController..

So it will be something like this inside your navigationViewController class:

```
YourTableViewController *tableView = (YourTableViewController*)[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
tableView.yourPublicProperty = whateverValueYouWant;
```

-Your tableView will be the object at index 0 unless you have other VC's also embedded..So you can just print out your vc's and then figure it out from there if you do.

Comment: but that code would have to be in the UINavigationcontroller class in order for it to be caught.  Are you suggesting that i create a custom UINavigationController to pass the value along?  Also to clarify, it isn't so much a segue as it is that (dot)-(dot) symbol that you see when you drag and drop a navigation controller onto the storyboard and you see a tableview connected to it.

Comment: I guess i misunderstand your problem. You want to pass a value from a navVC into a tableVC? And are you or are you not segueing into the tableView controller from the navigation view controller?

Comment: After your edit, im assuming you mean that the tableView is embedded (ie the dot dot?) inside the navigation controller?

Comment: yes, the problem is that i dragged a navigation controller onto the storyboard and it came attached to a tableview.  i linked that tableview to my custom tableview class.  When i instantiate the view controller from the name "nav", which is the storyboard id of the navigation controller, i get the navigation controller as the view controller being instantiated; so how do pass a value from where i instantiate the view to the tableview controller?

Comment: ah, embedded... yes that was the word i was looking for,  so yes the table view is embedded in the navigation controller.

Comment: K i just added an answer to reflect it being embedded instead of segueing from one to the other...is that what your looking for?

Answer (score 3):

I know this is already answered (nicely done ttarules), but I thought I'd pass along some extra comments.  It's very common to have some type of view controller embedded in a navigation controller.  Wrapping a standard view controller in a navigation controller then doing a modal segue to it, gives you a modal scene, with a nice nav bar to put buttons in, etc.  Also on the iPad, replace segues can commonly use navigation controllers. It's all about how you design things, but if you know how the controllers stack up and how to easily reference them, you will have more design options.  Here is a snippet you can use in your prepare for segue method to easily detect it.

```
if ([segue.destinationViewController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]) {

    //note: have to get reference to next vc through nav controller
    self.nextViewController = [[(UINavigationController*)segue.destinationViewController viewControllers]lastObject];
}
else {
    self.nextViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
}
```